# Stacking my jquery code for inputs with parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I have written code that moves label up after writing smth in the inputs like in photo[image: form]

However, I decided to add the Parsley.js file to my website for validating the form, but it stacks with labels after errors are shown[image]. I have changed places of codes, it did not worked as well. Also some inputs do not get colored when there is validation error. Here is the whole code of that page. I didn't get where can be the problem.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">

<style type="text/css">


html {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

/* Colors */
/* ---------------------------------------- */
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

form {
  padding: 4em 10%;
}

h2.heading {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  color: #506982;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #506982;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.controls {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.controls input[type="text"],
.controls input[type="email"],
.controls input[type="tel"],
.controls textarea,
.controls button,
.controls select {
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  color: #888;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.controls input[type="text"]:focus, .controls input[type="text"]:hover,
.controls input[type="email"]:focus,
.controls input[type="email"]:hover,
.controls input[type="tel"]:focus,
.controls input[type="tel"]:hover,
.controls textarea:focus,
.controls textarea:hover,
.controls button:focus,
.controls button:hover,
.controls select:focus,
.controls select:hover {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #9FB1C1;
}
.controls input[type="text"]:focus + label, .controls input[type="text"]:hover + label,
.controls input[type="email"]:focus + label,
.controls input[type="email"]:hover + label,
.controls input[type="tel"]:focus + label,
.controls input[type="tel"]:hover + label,
.controls textarea:focus + label,
.controls textarea:hover + label,
.controls button:focus + label,
.controls button:hover + label,
.controls select:focus + label,
.controls select:hover + label {
  color: #077ABC; 
  cursor: text;
}

.controls input[type="date"]:focus + label {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.controls .fa-sort {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 17px;
  color: #999;
}
.controls select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.controls label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 12px;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s, top 0.3s, background-color 0.8s;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s, top 0.3s, background-color 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s, top 0.3s, background-color 0.8s;
  transition: color 0.3s, top 0.3s, background-color 0.8s;
}
.controls label.active {
  top: -15px;
  color: #555;
  background-color: white;
}
.controls textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 200px;
}
.controls button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0db4eb;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 0;
}
.controls button:hover {
  background-color: #0066ff;
}

#addcourse {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

input.form-control {
  border-bottom: none;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  background-color: #fff;
}


.qiymetinput {
    position: relative;
}

.qiymetinput:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    content: 'AZN';
    font-size: 35px;
}

input.parsley-success,
select.parsley-success,
textarea.parsley-success {
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #DFF0D8;
  border: 1px solid #D6E9C6;
}

input.parsley-error,
select.parsley-error,
textarea.parsley-error {
  color: #B94A48;
  background-color: #F2DEDE;
  border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
}

.parsley-errors-list {
  margin: 2px 0 13px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.parsley-errors-list.filled {
  opacity: 1;
}

</style>
<section id="addcourse">
    <div class="addcoursediv">
        <div id="messages"></div>

        <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'rex-forms', 'name' => 'addcourse', 'id' => 'addcourse', 'data-parsley-validate' => ''); ?>
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('courses/addcourse', $attributes); ?>

            <!--  General -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <h2 class="heading">General</h2>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="floatLabel" name="name" data-parsley-minlength="3" required="">
      <label for="name">Название курсов</label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
        <select class="floatLabel" id="duration" name="duration" required="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1 Месяц</option>
        <option value="2">2 Месяца</option>
        <option value="3">3 Месяца</option>
        <option value="4">4 Месяца</option>
        <option value="5">5 Месяцев</option>
        <option value="6">6 Месяцев</option>
        <option value="7">7 Месяцев</option>
        <option value="8">8 Месяцев</option>
        <option value="9">9 Месяцев</option>
        <option value="10">10 Месяцев</option>
        <option value="11">11 Месяцев</option>
        <option value="12">12+ Месяцев</option>
      </select>
      <label for="fruit">Длительность</label>

    </div>

    <div class="controls">
      <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
      <select class="floatLabel" id="certification" name="certification" required="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">Нет</option>
        <option value="1">Да</option>
      </select>
      <label for="certification">Сертификат</label>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
      <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
      <select class="floatLabel" id="category" name="category" required="">
      <option value="">
      </option>
        <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
        <optgroup label="<?= $cat['name_rus']; ?>">

            <?php 
            $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => $cat['id']));
            ?>
            <?php foreach($query->result() as $subcat): ?>
            <option value="<?= $subcat->id; ?>"><?= $subcat->name_rus; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <label for="certification">Категория</label>
    </div>

    <div class="controls qiymetinput">
      <input type="text" id="price" class="floatLabel" name="price" data-parsley-type="integer" required="">
      <label for="price">Стоимость</label>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#begining").datepicker({ 
              format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
              todayHighlight: true
          });
          $("#begining").on("change", function () {
              var fromdate = $(this).val();
          });
      }); 
    </script>


    <div class="controls">
    <input class="form-control floatLabel" name="begining" id="begining" type="text" required="">
      <label for="begining">Начало</label>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){
          $.each( CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change",function(e) {
              for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
              CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
            });
          });
      });
    </script>

    <h2 class="heading">Description</h2>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea name="description" id="description" required=""></textarea>
    </div>

    <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('description');
    </script>

    <h2 class="heading">Purpose</h2>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea name="purpose" id="purpose" required=""></textarea><br><br>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('purpose');
    </script>
  </div>


 </form>


    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($){
  function floatLabel(inputType){
    $(inputType).each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      // on focus add cladd active to label
      $this.focus(function(){
        $this.next().addClass("active");
      });
      //on blur check field and remove class if needed
      $this.blur(function(){
        if($this.val() === '' || $this.val() === 'blank'){
          $this.next().removeClass();
        }
      });
    });
  }
  // just add a class of "floatLabel to the input field!"
  floatLabel(".floatLabel");
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to specify a particular `data-parsley-errors-container`.

Comment: it worked good, but it does not show any errors for textarea. Where can be the problem? Here is a screenshot https://yadi.sk/i/esxE1LFw3MPmbo